Unable to make an API request between two servers
I'm gonna interact with a secure API as my other server on Apache, from my Next.js 14 app with fetch method, getting TypeError: fetch failed and UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT. I don't know how it is going on but I can make request from my localhost flawlessly while I'm testing, but the same code is not working on the server. Indeed I proxied Next server that is serving on localhost:3000 to Nginx server in the same machine with the following config;
server {
   listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
   listen 80 default_server deferred;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   if ($host = www.example.com) {
       return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
   }

   if ($host = example.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }

   return 404;
}

server {
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   listen 443 ssl http2;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   root /var/www/html;

   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_redirect off;
   }
}

I make request from a server component, and it is also requesting to a route handler. Actually I use two fetch methods, one from a server component to my route handler, and another within the route handler talking to the external API. I also tested another approach of having a single method only within my server component requesting directly to the API.
const endpoint = "https://ws.apiprovider.com/api/v1/rest/pattern"
const token = "*********"

const data = {
    key1: 'some_string'
    key2: 'some_other_string'
}

const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        token: token
    }
}

const res = await fetch(endpoint, requestOptions)
const jsonRes = await res.json()

The second server is serving a functional API for a long time and many users are using it.
Tested on my localhost and also Insomnia and it works, but not works with wget or curl on the server.
I observed SELinux denial audits and tested setenforce 0 temporarily and also disabled firewalld.
It's just like they can't communicate in some way, cause I have other connections to other REST APIs from my app without any issues.
Any other thing to evaluate?

So which fetch request failed ? the server component one or the route handler one ?

Both approaches will fail.

Check SSL configuration also make sure the ports are not blocked by firewall. These are two most common issues.

@AliSheikhpour firewall-cmd --list-services: cockpit dhcpv6-client dns http https ssh. Any other ports may be required? Do I have to open them by port command?

If you are using any other port rather than 80 and 443 , add it like this:
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
